# Proving convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty cos(n^2\pi)\cdot(\sqrt{n+11}-\sqrt{n+2}) $

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

I want to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty cos(n^2\pi)\cdot(\sqrt{n+11}-\sqrt{n+2}) $ is convergent (or divergent).

I am lost on how to prove it. Could someone please show me or give me a hint? I assume I would need to use one of the criterias for determining convergence?

I tried to multiplicate it by $ \frac {\sqrt{n+11}+\sqrt{n+2}}{\sqrt{n+11}+\sqrt{n+2}} $ to see if I could get something more useful, but without any luck.

Comment: $n^2$ is odd, even, odd, even,..., what does that tell you about $\cos(n^2\pi)$?

Comment: @copper.hat oh, yeah, it tells me that it is basicly $ (-1)^n $, which means I have to series probably converging to a limit from booth sides.

Comment: If $a_n \ge 0$ and $a_n \downarrow 0$ then $\sum_n (-1)^n a_n$ converges.

Comment: @copper.hat I got that the limit is 0 for both even and odd n. Could you please show me how to prove that it is decreasing?

Comment: Multiply as you suggested in your answer, this will show that the $a_n$ are decreasing with limit zero.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\sum a_n$ the given series then

$$a_n=(-1)^n(\sqrt{n+11}-\sqrt{2+n})=\frac{9(-1)^n}{\sqrt{11+n}+\sqrt{2+n}}$$
and we deduce the convergence using the Leibniz rule.

Comment: Yeah, I got something similiar on my own, but I am not allowed to use integrals (i.e. Leibniz integral rule) as we have yet to learn them.. and I don't see how I could use any of the other convergence criteria on this.

Comment: By Leibniz rule I mean [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series).

Comment: I tried to figure it out using the wikipedia defenition, but I got a little lost. So I want to show that its decreasing and that it has a limit? I got that the limit is 0 for both even and odd n. Could you please show me how to prove that it is decreasing?